# How do i add EIP-1559 functionality to ERC-20 contract using solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, precompiled-contracts, eip-1559

Trying to adapt this solidity code from https://github.com/CodeWithJoe2020/ERC20Token/blob/main/ERC20.sol

Using remix

Basic token creation contract, but it will not create a contract due to EIP-1559 code not added

Comment: What error did you get? What were you doing? EIP-1559 is backward compatible with existing wallets, and a contract doesn't need to make any change.

Comment: I was getting an error, saying that my wallet requires EIP-1559 to make the contract, It was a problem using a hardware wallet to create the contract, I used a different wallet and it worked now.

Comment: If you solved the problem that way it would be nice if you can write that as answer so the question can be marked as resolved and help others in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

Using a hardware wallet was causing the problem here. I created the contract using a regular metamask wallet.